# How to retrieve header fields from a response string on Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I'm using Swift 3 with Alamofire for my server calls. This is my code

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(
        url,
        method: .post,
        parameters: parameters,
        headers: headers)
        .responseString{ response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("response headerfields ", response.response?.allHeaderFields ?? "no headerfields")
                //completionHandler(value as? NSDictionary, nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("signin_post error: ", error)
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
    }
```

How do i properly get the header fields from above response? I get a SUCCESS for my response result but thats it. I have a code written in Objective-c for this which is working correctly.

```
[manager POST:url parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"signInWithUserName Success JSON: %@", responseObject);

        if ([task.response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *r = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
            NSString *responsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            if(responsString != nil){
                NSString *authToken = [[r allHeaderFields] valueForKey:XAUTHTOKEN];
                NSLog(@"X-AUTH-TOKEN %@ ", authToken);

            //....
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can guide me on how do this with Swift 3.

Comment: can you print `response.response` ? what you get in it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `response.request.allHTTPHeaderFields` to get the headers from alamofire response object.
Try this,

```
Alamofire.request(
        url,
        method: .post,
        parameters: parameters,
        headers: headers)
        .responseString{ response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("response headerfields \(response.request?.allHTTPHeaderFields)")
                //completionHandler(value as? NSDictionary, nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("signin_post error: ", error)
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
    }
```